# System packages not detected by the Oracle installer

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, oracle-database

I am installing Oracle 11g 32bit on Ubuntu Linux and the setup shows the following error message on `Prerequisite Checks` screen:

```
This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the package "make-3.80" is available on the system. (more details)
Expected Value
 : make-3.80
Actual Value
 : missing
```

On the commandline when I run `sudo apt-get install make` I get:

```
make is already the newest version.
```

There are lot of other dependencies that setup is not able to find. Why can't it find them?

Comment: What version of ubuntu? What version(s) of make is installed (`dpkg -s make|grep Version`)?

Comment: @Patrick Lubuntu 12.10, Make Version: 3.81-8.2ubuntu2